# GRASS New/Open Mapset not available ( QGIS 2.18.7) on Mac OS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2, mac, grass-7.0

I have QGIS 2.18 and the option to create a New Mapset is unavailable to me. GRASS is installed but when I go to the Plug-Ins>GRASS only Open GRASS Tools and GRASS Options are available to me. These are also the only icons in the GRASS toolbar.

How can I work with GRASS?

[image]

Update, I also notice this ('Currently selected GRASS installation is not valid'):
[image]

Comment: Which QGIS 2.18.x version are you using? Could you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/241680/edit) your question to include a screenshot please? An alternative could be to run the `GRASS GIS 7.x.x` program which somes with your QGIS, create a new mapset through that then open it in QGIS. I still have 2.18.2 but is working fine.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I'm not sure how top open GRASS directly without downloading it standalone. It doesn't seem to appear anywhere as an application?
(I'm using a Mac)

Comment: Please add the solution as new answer and accept it to close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my Custom path to: `/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/grass7`

Comment: Mine was in `/Applications/QGIS3.14.app/Contents/Resources/grass7` and I set it in under the tab: `Plugins/GRASS/GRASS Options/Custom`

Answer (score 1):

I too had this error with QGIS 3.6.1 on Windows 10. The exact error message was :

```
GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in 'D:/program files/QGIS 3.6/apps/grass/grass76/' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.
```

I wondered if having spaces in the file path was a problem i.e. `program files`.

So, I copied the folder `grass76` from my install location `D:/program files/QGIS 3.6/apps/grass/` to `D:/`.

I then went back to plugins > grass > grass options and changed the custom directory to reflect the new location `D:/grass76`.

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I did on Windows [what Mike mentioned](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318053/107424), but instead I created a symbolic link from
`D:\grass78 <<===>> D:\Users\*user*\programs\QGIS 3.16.3\apps\grass\grass78`

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem aswell!