# QGIS 3.8 not running GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am having trouble initializing the GRASS plugin.I've tried un-installing and re-installing QGIS already. But the following message keeps appearing.

```
 GRASS init error : GRASS was not found in '/usr/local/opt/osgeo-grass/grass-base' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work.
```

Comment: See the answers to this question
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241680/grass-new-open-mapset-not-available-qgis-2-18-7-on-mac-os/242017#242017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the path to a previous working installation. You can use indifferently 3.6 or 3.8 version, GRASS works. QGIS 3.10 does not install GRASS correctly.

[image: Custom your path]
[image: Select GRASS Mapset]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but then I started running QGIS 3.8.2 with GRASS 7.6.1 instead of the regular QGIS installation and it worked again. *(I had the same problem back in 3.4)*

Answer (score 1):

I try to give a solution.

I created the `/osgeo-grass` folder in the `/usr/opt` directory and i copied and pasted the `/grass` folder contained in the QGIS3.8.app. So i renamed the folder as `/grass-base`.

I then restarted **QGIS3.10** and it seems that everything is OK.

**Some tests are necessary**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**FIRST TEST -  OK**

[image]